# Trying to make a Discord bot using asyncio

Tags: discord, discord.py

It says `asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`
in `line 71` that is last line of code `bot.run()`.

What I exactly want from bot is when users type !authorize they give my bot access to join servers for them and when any server admin [bot might be on multiple server's] types !invite <sever_link> the bot should join the server link provided by the server admin for all the users that authorized my bot to join new servers for them.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # enable the privileged gateway intent
os.environ['DISCORD_CLIENT_ID'] = '123' //actual id
client_id = os.environ['DISCORD_CLIENT_ID']
os.environ['DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'xyz' //actual secret code
client_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET']
redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/xyz'
oauth2_session = OAuth2Session(client=BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id))
authorization_url = 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?abc' //actual url
token = None
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

async def authorize_user(user):
    global token
    if token is None:
        await user.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Authorization Required", description=f"Please authorize me using the following link:\n{authorization_url}"))
        return

    await user.send("You are already authorized.")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global token
    token = oauth2_session.fetch_token(
        token_url='https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token',
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret
    )
    print('Bot is ready')

@bot.command()
async def authorize(ctx):
    await authorize_user(ctx.author)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def invite(ctx, *, message):
    if not message.startswith('!invite '):
        await ctx.send('Invalid command. Usage: `!invite `')
        return

    invite_link = message[8:]

    async def join_server(invite_url):
        parsed_url = urlparse(invite_url)
        query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
        server_id = query_params.get('guild_id', [None])[0]
        if server_id is None:
            await ctx.send('Invalid invite URL')
            return

        guild = bot.get_guild(int(server_id))
        if guild is None:
            await ctx.send('Invalid server')
            return

        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token["access_token"]}'}
        member_tasks = []
        for member in await guild.fetch_members().flatten():
            if member.bot:
                continue
            member_tasks.append(requests.put(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{server_id}/members/{member.id}', headers=headers))

        for task in member_tasks:
            response = await task
            if response.status_code != 201:
                await ctx.send(f'Error adding user {member.display_name} ({member.id}): {response.status_code}')
        await ctx.send('All authorized members have been added to the server')

    await join_server(invite_link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run('token') //token
<
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So you just want to make so that your bot joins servers? Why not just use the link provided by discord?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example, I hope it helps. You need to replace the token.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio, os, signal

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
token = "token"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

"""
events and commands
"""

async def main():
    # This line is responsible for the CTRL+C key combination to stop the bot     without error
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda s, f: asyncio.create_task(os._exit(0)))
    async with bot:
        print("Starting bot...")
        await bot.start(token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        exit(1)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?